# How to fetch only free videos from YouTube search api(V3)?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I am using YouTube Data's Search API v3 to fetch videos. I am able to fetch videos properly with the below mentioned HTTPS `GET` request. But this API is listing paid videos too, like the one having the ID [`FKUvkKsTzV8`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKUvkKsTzV8). That I would like to skip from fetching.

I have gone through the Search API documentation, but was unable to identify the filter for fetching only free videos -- not paid videos.

Please suggest me the filter to fetch only free videos from Search API, if any.

Here is the URL of my HTTPS `GET` request:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=5&q=frozen&key=[My api key]&type=video&order=relevance`

**Edited with more information:**

The given video is an example, which will play in some regions only. So adding some more similar to the above mentioned video. I would like to skip these kind of videos from my search result.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMWjixQbqXY

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zat88Rsxp94

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2YQ9W0BP2Gw

The videos which are free to play is given below

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TavVZMewpY

Comment: have you checked videoLicense

Comment: Not sure what you meant by quote *paid video* and *preview video*. The video you linked above shows off as *unavailable*. As far as I know, there are no such categories as those of yours in use by the API. Please elaborate a bit -- and thus [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64099879/edit) your question's text above.

Comment: Hi @DaImTo can you please let me know which license can be used to fetch only free videos?

Comment: @stvar, edited question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the [`Videos resource`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource) meta-data attached to the videos of which ID you mentioned within your question, I deduce that your issue may be reformulated as follows:

> Do use the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint for to search for videos -- using the parameter [`q`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#q) as needed --, but exclude from the result set that's provided by the endpoint those videos that *are not allowed to be viewed* in certain (given) regions.

The `Videos resource` attached to each video does contain the info that specifies that particular condition above, namely the properties:

> [**contentDetails.regionRestriction**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.regionRestriction) (object)
> The `regionRestriction` object contains information about the countries where a video is (or is not) viewable. The object will contain either the `contentDetails.regionRestriction.allowed` property or the `contentDetails.regionRestriction.blocked` property.
>
> [**contentDetails.regionRestriction.allowed[]**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.regionRestriction.allowed%5B%5D) (list)
> A list of region codes that identify countries where the video is viewable. If this property is present and a country is not listed in its value, then the video is blocked from appearing in that country. If this property is present and contains an empty list, the video is blocked in all countries.
>
> [**contentDetails.regionRestriction.blocked[]**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.regionRestriction.blocked%5B%5D) (list)
> A list of region codes that identify countries where the video is blocked. If this property is present and a country is not listed in its value, then the video is viewable in that country. If this property is present and contains an empty list, the video is viewable in all countries.

Unfortunately, one *cannot specify explicitly* to the `Search.list` endpoint *a filter based on these properties*.

Nevertheless, you may retain as much IDs as you can from `Search.list` and then query the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint for precisely these properties with the purpose of filtering out programatically the videos that are not viewable in the regions of your interest.

The URL that will invoke the `Videos.list` endpoint would look like:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=$APP_KEY&id=$VIDEO_IDS&part=contentDetails,id&fields=items(id,contentDetails(regionRestriction))&maxResults=$VIDEO_COUNT`

where `$APP_KEY` is your API key, `$VIDEO_IDS` is a comma-separated list of video IDs and `$VIDEO_COUNT` is the number of video IDs that `$VIDEO_IDS` contains. (Note that `$VIDEO_COUNT` should not exceed `50`.)

Note that the URL above is using the parameter [`fields`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#fields) for to obtain from the endpoint only the properties that are of actual use. (It's always good to ask from the API only the info that is really needed.)

When setting `$VIDEO_COUNT` to `5` and `$VIDEO_IDS` to

`FKUvkKsTzV8,ZMWjixQbqXY,Zat88Rsxp94,2YQ9W0BP2Gw,7TavVZMewpY`

within the URL above, `Videos.list` returns the following JSON text:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "FKUvkKsTzV8",
      "contentDetails": {
        "regionRestriction": {
          "allowed": [
            "BE",
            "NL"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "ZMWjixQbqXY",
      "contentDetails": {
        "regionRestriction": {
          "allowed": [
            "NL"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "Zat88Rsxp94",
      "contentDetails": {
        "regionRestriction": {
          "allowed": [
            "BE",
            "NL"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2YQ9W0BP2Gw",
      "contentDetails": {
        "regionRestriction": {
          "allowed": [
            "PE",
            "KG",
            "PA",
            "PL",
            "PH",
            "TZ",
            "TW",
            "TH",
            "TJ",
            "TM",
            "PY",
            "KZ",
            "GR",
            "CY",
            "GT",
            "CZ",
            "CV",
            "CR",
            "GA",
            "CL",
            "CO",
            "CI",
            "SN",
            "SI",
            "SK",
            "SE",
            "NP",
            "KH",
            "NI",
            "ID",
            "NO",
            "NL",
            "NA",
            "NE",
            "PT",
            "BZ",
            "BY",
            "BW",
            "BO",
            "BJ",
            "BF",
            "BE",
            "ZW",
            "MU",
            "MT",
            "VE",
            "EE",
            "EC",
            "IS",
            "MD",
            "RW",
            "ML",
            "AZ",
            "ZM",
            "LV",
            "AR",
            "AO",
            "AM",
            "TG",
            "SG",
            "DK",
            "LT",
            "UZ",
            "UY",
            "DO",
            "HU",
            "LA",
            "HN",
            "UG",
            "LK",
            "UA",
            "FI",
            "SV"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "7TavVZMewpY",
      "contentDetails": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

This response indicates that the video identified by `FKUvkKsTzV8` is viewable only in `NL` and `BE` regions, while the video identified by `7TavVZMewpY` has no region restrictions at all (i.e. is freely-viewable everywhere).

Now, it's quite simple to access the properties under the object `items[].contantDetails.regionRestriction` for to exclude from a *filtered result set* those video IDs that are not viewable within the regions of your interest.

---

**Addendum**

Not sure that what follows will help, but nevertheless, I'll have to mention that the `Search.list` endpoint does have the following parameter:

> [**regionCode**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#regionCode) (string)
> The `regionCode` parameter instructs the API to return search results for videos that can be viewed in the specified country. The parameter value is an [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/country_names_and_code_elements.htm) country code.

The above official specification does not indicate whether `regionCode` allows one to specify *a set of regions*, or, otherwise, how to specify to `regionCode` *the set of all regions*.

Comment: Hi @stvar, appreciates your effort. Really very good information. We can get the region based result directly with regionCode parameter in search query it self.  My problem is some of the videos are paid versions. Those are playing trailer in youtube desktop website but not in my application. So i want to exclude them from result.

Comment: reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#regionCode

Comment: @Raghu Mudem: Do you have an embedded YouTube player within your application? Can you indicate one such video that has a trailer playable on YouTube's site?

Comment: Yes, My app has youtube player.
1. Plays in both youtube site and my application.
Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TavVZMewpY

2. Plays in youtube site but not in my application. Link: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMWjixQbqXY.

Reason is simple url 1 is free and url 2 has rent option. So i would like to exclude these rent option url from my search result.

Comment: `ZMWjixQbqXY` does not play on my browser (I'm outside `BE` and `NL`). None of the videos you quoted above -- with the exception of `7TavVZMewpY`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I see no video property published by the API that would imply the info you describe.

Comment: Yes, Unfortunately there is no information to identify pair or free videos. So unable to play paid version of movie trailers.

Comment: Are the kind of videos described by the article [About movies & TV shows](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9674101) what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to exclude all the videos which are eligible for Buy or Rent. I just need a search for only free videos.

Comment: But [paid content was discontinued on January 1, 2018](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7515570?hl=en). This fact (very much likely) implies that currently and for the future the API cannot have means to filter such type of videos.